# message authentication negotiate login and password connect in browser login.teamviewer.com (managment console)

Tags: teamviewer, negotiate

Good afternoon,
when connecting to a computer using login.teamviewer.com (management console)
I get the message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzjt4.png)

login.teamviewer.com (managment console)

message authentication: 'negotiate'

requires login and password connect

What is it? What do I do to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a teamviewer account and attach computers to that account. on login.teamviewer.com yo have to login with your account, then, you're going to be able to see the computers attached to your account and manage them

Comment: So it is, see what the message goes unclear, it's a problem only through the browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzjt4.png

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the language. But I assume from my exprience using teamviewer it is the login view